# curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL (but curl actually executes the POST)

Tags: bash, curl

My end goal is to run this command in .gitlab-ci.yml.

I'm testing it in both bash shell and in a gitlab-ci.yml process at the moment.

The process started by the api PUT call is started and runs successfully but because the curl returns with an error code the gitlab-ci process exits with an error immediately.

The error message:
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

`curl -X PUT "http://AAA.BBB.CC.DDD:8443/api/v4/schedules/84ce2778-3496-4933-a3c2-f07f64637c92/runNow?api_key=0WhA6P1j70Kta2fW" -d --header 'Accept:application/json' --header 'AccessKey:0WhA6P1j70Kta2fW'`

I tried with single quotes around the URL and received the same error message.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why are you sending an api key and an access key?

Comment: From the website of the api provider that was how the example api call was specified.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted to provide some data to send to the `-d` option.

`-d` takes the next argument as data and that happens to be `--header`, which makes the argument following `--header` get treated as as a URL since it doesn't start with a dash.

Also note that it looks like you've exposed your access key here. Make sure that is not so anymore.

Comment: I'll give that a try when I get back to the office next week. The api provider recommended that flag to eliminate a 411 "Length Required" error.   The access key is a fake one.

Comment: Did they perhaps them mean `-d ""` ?

Answer (score 1):

With an additional suggestion from the company, this turns out to be the solution:

```
curl -X PUT "http://AAA.BBB.CC.DDD:8443/api/v4/schedules/84ce2778-3496-4933-a3c2-f07f64637c92/runNow?api_key=0WhA6P1j70Kta2fW" --header 'Content-Length:0' --header 'Accept:application/json' --header 'AccessKey:0WhA6P1j70Kta2fW'
```